# I want to change the color of a paintComponent() object when a condition is met

Tags: java, arrays, swing, paintcomponent, repaint

I can't seem to get my head around this, I know that repaint() is involved but not sure how to use it. 
Here is my code

```
public CarPanel()
    {
        repaint();
        rects = new Rectangle[]
        {
            new Rectangle(25, 35, 30, 80, Color.GREEN,"8"),
            new Rectangle(65, 35, 30, 80, Color.GREEN,"7"),
            new Rectangle(105, 35, 30, 80, Color.GREEN,"6"),
            new Rectangle(145, 65, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"2"),
            new Rectangle(185, 65, 30, 50, Color.green,"1"),
            new Rectangle(25, 170, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"13"),
            new Rectangle(65, 170, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"12"),
            new Rectangle(105, 170, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"11"),
            new Rectangle(145, 170, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"3"),
            new Rectangle(190, 160, 92, 80, Color.BLACK,"Attendant Station"),
            new Rectangle(25, 280, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"15"),
            new Rectangle(65, 280, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"14"),
            new Rectangle(105, 280, 30, 80, Color.GREEN,"10"),
            new Rectangle(145, 280, 30, 80, Color.GREEN,"9"),
            new Rectangle(185, 280, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"5"),
            new Rectangle(225, 280, 30, 50, Color.GREEN,"4")     
        };
    }//end carPark

    public void changeShapeColor(){

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        this.setBackground(Color.white);

        for (Rectangle rect : rects) {               
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.drawString(rect.number, rect.x, rect.y);
            g.setColor(rect.color); 
            g.fillRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.w, rect.h);
        }//end for
    }//end paintComponent
}//end JPanel
```

When a condition is met elsewhere in the code I want to change the color from green to red.
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void changeShapeColor(Color newColor) {
    for (Rectangle rect : rects) {
        rect.color = newColor;
    }
}
```

and then call the `changeShapeColor`-method from whenever your condition is changed. And make sure your component is invalidated, so it will be redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to change the Rectangle to take a color function instead of a color, so use a code structure like this:

```
public class Rectangle {
   private ColorFunction function;
   // ... etc

   public Color getColor() { return function.getColor(); }
}

public interface ColorFunction {
   public Color getColor();
}

public class MyColorChoice implements ColorFunction {
   public Color getColor() {
      return isConditionMet() ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN;
   }
}
```

Comment: how would I be able to change specific rectangle objects within the array? For example something like this.. rects[2].Color = Color.red